# How do I apply the mean value theorem here?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the following question

> Suppose the functions $f_n(n=1,2, \ldots)$ are defined on the open interval $(0,1)$ and that $f_n$ tends uniformly on $(0,1)$ to a function $f$. If the $f_n$ are continuous, show that $f$ is continuous. If the $f_n$ are differentiable, show by example that $f$ need not be differentiable.
> Assume now that each $f_n$ is differentiable and the derivatives $f_n^{\prime}$ converge uniformly on $(0,1)$. For any given $c \in(0,1)$, we define functions $g_{c, n}$ by
> $$
> g_{c, n}(x)= \begin{cases}\frac{f_n(x)-f_n(c)}{x-c} & \text { for } x \neq c, \\ f_n^{\prime}(c) & \text { for } x=c .\end{cases}
> $$
> Show that each $g_{c, n}$ is continuous. Using the general principle of uniform convergence (the Cauchy criterion) and the Mean Value Theorem, or otherwise, prove that the functions $g_{c, n}$ converge uniformly to a continuous function $g_c$ on $(0,1)$, where
> $$
> g_c(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} \quad \text { for } x \neq c .
> $$
> Deduce that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$.

**Thoughts on the mean value theorem:** I would assume that they want us to use it in the context of
$$
|g_{c,n}(x) - g_{c,m}(x)| 
$$
where we can use it to get that this is
$$
\leq |f'_n (\zeta) - f'_n (\omega) |
$$
for some $\zeta, \omega \in (c,x)$. But here I can not assert that the right hand side goes uniformly to zero as we need not have $f'(\zeta) = f'(\omega$.

**How I went about solving it without it** The way that I did this part was just by partitioning the region $(0,1)$ into three parts - $(0,c-r)$, $(c-r,c+r)$ and $(c+r,1)$ for a suitable $r$ that I get from local uniform convergence, and then just look into each case separately. Nothing bad but just tedious.

I really don't see how one uses the mean value thoerem. I would greatly appreciate any help.

**Question:** How do I apply the mean value theorem to show that $g_{c,n}$ is uniformly convergent?

Comment: "I was able to do the question in its integrity without using the Mean Value Theorem." : Please edit your posting, to present your work in a clear, well organized manner.  Also, given the length of your (good) description of the assigned problem, please start your posting with a summary paragraph that explains that you are going to show the originally assigned question, followed by all of your work, and that your question is ... (i.e. state your precise question in the first paragraph of your posting).

Comment: @user2661923 My work is on paper and it was more than 4 pages. This part of the question should not have anything to do with the rest of the question - this should be a clear application of the mean value theorem in order to show uniform convergence.

Comment: The fact that your work is lengthy is a very good point.  However, it is entirely plausible that your work may (without your realizing it) utilize the concepts inherent in the mean value theorem.  Then, for a MathSE reviewer to answer your *explicit question*, they would need to dissect your work, show where you (perhaps) actually did use the Mean Value Theorem, and (perhaps) show a more elegant (i.e. less lengthy) approach.

Comment: I have now edited the question, hopefully the structure is more clear.

Comment: I will try to see if I can summarise by work so that the readers can see my exact thought process. However, I do not think that the way was intended as I doubt that there should be any partitioning on the domain.

Comment: As I interpret your *explicit question*, what you are really asking is : what is the *intent* of the problem composer, and how were you supposed to provide an answer **consistent with that intent**.  This probably requires the approach that I am suggesting.

Comment: One suggestion that I have that will improve the overall clarity of your presentation is to make your posting a **partial self-answer posting**.  That is, do just as I suggested, but show your work in one of the answer boxes.  This will make it easier for a MathSE reviewer to focus directly on your shown work.

Comment: One point: You talk about being consistent with the intent. But the problem said to prove the result "using ... the MVT, **or otherwise**". I.e., the intent was *nothing more* than that you prove the result. Using the MVT was only a suggestion, not a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to apply mean value theorem to the function $f_n-f_m$.
Let $x,c\in (0,1)$ with $x\ne c$.
By mean value theorem, there is $\xi\in(0,1)$ such that
$$
\begin{align*}
f_n'(\xi)-f_m'(\xi)&=\frac{(f_n(x)-f_m(x))-(f_n(c)-f_m(c))}{x-c} \\
&= \frac{f_n(x)-f_n(c)}{x-c}-\frac{f_m(x)-f_m(c)}{x-c} \\
&= g_{n,c}(x)-g_{m,c}(x).
\end{align*}
$$
Now, by the uniform convergence of $(f'_n)$, we can find large enough $N$ such that if $n,m>N$, then $| f_n'(\xi)-f_m'(\xi) |<\varepsilon$.